# SSH config use wildcard portion of Host in target HostName

Tags: ssh, regex

I'm trying to define a compact SSH config that matches 3 host naming schemes but also matching many wildcard possibilities, all with a single `Host` definition like so:

```
Host xyz-*.domain.com xyz-* xyz*
  HostName xyz-%h.domain.com
  User ubuntu
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
  ProxyCommand nc -x proxy.company.com %h %p
```

The idea is to match all these hosts, but connect only to the fully qualified version (to reduce the # of entries in the "`known_hosts`" file):

- **`xyz-dev.domain.com`** = `xyz-dev` = `xyzdev`
- **`xyz-test.domain.com`** = `xyz-test` = `xyztest`
- **`xyz-prod.domain.com`** = `xyz-prod` = `xyzprod`
- *etc.*

I know the the above `HostName` value won't work, as I'm trying to find a way to perform a **"regex capture"** of sorts in the `Host` and use it in the `HostName` expansion.

By using some more advanced config syntax, I managed to come up with a much less readable form that mostly works except the need to still manually accept host keys or having them ignored altogether (not ideal), which still automatically adds them into the "`known_hosts`" file.

```
Match exec "echo %h | grep -Eq '^xyz-?[^.]+(\.domain\.com|)$'"
  User ubuntu
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
  ProxyCommand nc -x proxy.company.com $(echo "%h" | sed -rn 's/^xyz-?([^.]+).*/xyz-\1/p').domain.com %p
  # StrictHostKeyChecking no
```

Is there a better way? It would be great if `HostName` itself allowed the same kind of shell manipulation that I'm using the `ProxyCommand` for, but I haven't seen any evidence for that.

Answer (score 2):

Your easiest option is to write a wrapper script, I'd say.

If you could drop `xyzfoo` and only keep `xyz-foo`, then it would be much simpler – just use two config blocks, one with %h and the other without:

```
Host xyz-*.domain.com
  User ubuntu
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
  ProxyCommand nc -x proxy.company.com %h %p

Host xyz-*
  Hostname %h.domain.com
  User ubuntu
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
  ProxyCommand nc -x proxy.company.com %h %p
```

In recent OpenSSH versions, you can also make use of two-pass processing:

```
Host xyz-*.domain.com
  User ubuntu
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
  ProxyCommand nc -x proxy.company.com %h %p

Host xyz-*
  CanonicalizeHostname yes
  CanonicalDomains domain.com
  # (nothing else)
```

or:

```
Match final xyz-*.domain.com
  User ubuntu
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
  ProxyCommand nc -x proxy.company.com %h %p

Host xyz-*
  Hostname %h.domain.com
  # (nothing else)
```

(The practical difference between these two is that 'CanonicalizeHostname' performs a live DNS check against a *list* of domains until it finds a match, making it suitable for `Host *`; meanwhile the '%h' approach is completely static – faster but limits you to exactly one domain per pattern.)

As for known_hosts entries, if you are managing the file manually (or generating it from a script), you could add all the aliases to the same entry:

```
xyz-foo.domain.com,xyz-foo,xyzfoo ssh-ed25519 AAAAC3NzaC1lZ...
xyz-bar.domain.com,xyz-bar,xyzbar ssh-ed25519 AAAAC3NzaC1lZ...
```

Comment: Since there's tab-completion on `Host` block aliases, it shouldn't make any difference on the CLI to drop the no-`-` aliases. If you drop them, `ssh xy`{TAB} becomes `ssh xyz-`, ready for you to type `prod` and go.

Comment: Haha, nice edit. I was just about to comment again, suggesting `CanonicalizeHostname`.